# Python/ SQL Statement - Use of parameters / injection protection?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have inherited some code similar to below.  I understand the concept of passing values to make a query dynamic(in this case field_id) but I don't understand what the benefit of taking the passed-in field_id list and putting it into a dictionary `parameters = {"logical_field_id": field_id}` before accessing the newly created dictionary to build the SQL statement. Along the same line why return `parameters=parameters` rather than just listing `parameters` in the return?  I assume this is all the make the request more secure but I would like to better understand of why/how as I need to take on a similar task on a slightly more complex query that is below

```
def get_related_art(self, field_id):                                               
    parameters = {"logical_field_id": field_id}
    sql = (
        "SELECT a.id AS id,"
        "  a.name AS name,"
        "  a.description AS description,"
        "  a.type AS type,"
        "  a.subtype AS subtype "
        " FROM ArtclTbl AS a INNER JOIN ("
        "   SELECT article_id AS id FROM LogFldArtclTbl"
        "     WHERE logical_field_id = %(logical_field_id)s"
        " ORDER BY a.name"
    )
    return self.query(sql, parameters=parameters)
```

My reason for asking this question is I was asked to parameterize this

```
 def get_group_fields(self, exbytes=None):

    parameters = {}
    where_clause = (
        f"WHERE eig_eb.ebyte in ({', '.join(str(e) for e in ebytes)})" if ebytes else ""
    )
    sql = (
        "SELECT l.id AS id, "
        "  eig_eb.ebyte AS ebyte, "
        "  eig.id AS instrument_group_id, "
        "  eig_lf.relationship_type AS relationship "
        ....
        f" {where_clause}"
    )
```

I started to modify code to iterate when setting the `parameters` and then accessing that value in the original location. This 'works' except now the query string returns ([ebyte1, ebyte2] instead of (ebyte1, ebyte2).  I could modify the string to work around this but i really wanted to understand the why of this first.

```
    parameters = {"exbytes": ', '.join(str(e) for e in exbytes)}
    ...
    where_clause = (
        f"WHERE eig_eb.exbyte in " + str(exbytes) if exbytes else ""
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74717854/5320906) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit of using named parameter placeholders is so you can pass the parameter values as a dict, and you can add values to that dict in any order. There's no benefit in the first example you show, because you only have one entry in the dict.

There's no benefit in the second example either, because the parameters are part of an `IN()` list, and there are no other parameterized parts of the query. The order of values in an `IN()` list is irrelevant. So you could just use positional parameters instead of named parameters.

```
where_clause = (
    f"WHERE eig_eb.ebyte in ({', '.join('%s' for e in ebytes)})" if ebytes else ""
)
```

Then you don't need a dict at all, you can just pass the `ebytes` list as the parameters.

Using the syntax `parameters=parameters` looks like a usage of keyword arguments to a Python function. I don't know the function `self.query()` in your example, but I suppose it accepts keyword arguments to implement optional arguments. The fact that your local variable is the same name as the keyword argument name is a coincidence.

Comment: I think you are correct here.  I figured out later that the 'benifit' is that the relevant security team that cares about this wants us to pass in any query variables as separate parameters rather then build it into the SQL string. So that is there reason for the extra hoops

Comment: I agree that SQL queries should be parameterized by default, not combined with string-concatenation or formatting. SQL injection is a real risk, and results in high-profile data breaches every month. Writing code securely should not be optional. There might be some exception cases where you really can't use query parameters, but they are rare, and this example is not an exception case.